# iAD with UITableViewController through Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview, iad

My first message here, so I need to tell you that I am kind of a noob in iOS developpement.
Sorry for that...

My problem is I walked through the Apple tutorial : [My Second iOS App](http://bit.ly/HSQljF).
And I use that tutorial to build my first really basic little app.
Now I would like to ad an iAd banner under the MasterViewController which is based on a UITaleViewController add through Storyboard.
I read that it is not possible to mix both and that I should embed my TableView into a UIView to get it work.

My question is : how do I do that through storyboarding without having to re-code my app from scratch ?

I hope my question is clear enough and that you can help.